# How to calculate equation using the column values and store output values one below the other using python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I have a dataset whose column values are to be used in an equation. 
`Max angle` is user defined and angular increments `Ang` will be the angular steps.

Suppose Max Angle = 30 , Angular Increment = 10, So I want 4 output rows for each input row. Only the angle must change with 0,10,20,30 in the equation.

1st column is my index 'ID'. My dataset consists of 300 rows. So my final output must have 300*4(angular steps) rows.

Sample dataset:

[image]

Edited Dataset:

```
data ='''
ID,1,2,3
23,0.88905321,0.500807892,0.499545029
105,0.334209544,0.24077062,0.345252261
47,0.020669404,0.154582048,0.044395524
28,0.07913145,0.987645061,0.421184162
23,0.5654544,0.879541062,0.456556261
105,0.45678404,0.789546214,0.456217524
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import *

data ='''
ID,1,2,3
23,0.88905321,0.500807892,0.499545029
105,0.334209544,0.24077062,0.345252261
47,0.020669404,0.154582048,0.044395524
28,0.07913145,0.987645061,0.421184162
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),index_col=0)
M = df.iloc[:,:]

#suppose
Max_ang = 30
Ang = 10

#Equation:
solution = 0.88905321*cos(Ang*(pi/180)) + 0.500807892*sin(Ang*(pi/180)) + 0.499545029 * sin(Ang*(pi/180))*cos(Ang*(pi/180))
```

Equation:

solution = Column1_val x cos(Ang x (pi/180)) + Column2_val x sin(Ang x (pi/180)) + Column3_val x sin(Ang x (pi/180)) x cos(Ang x (pi/180))

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Which pandas version do you have? `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: Version : 0.24.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a `for loop` with `iterrows` here, which will be quite slow.

Here's a vectorized solution using `numpy broadcasting`.

First we get your dataframe in the correct format with `reindex` and `index.repeat`:

```
import numpy as np

Max_ang = 30
Ang = 10
Angels = np.arange(0,Max_ang+Ang,step=Ang).tolist()

df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(len(Angels)))
df['Ang'] = Angels * df.index.nunique()

pi_div_180 = np.pi/180

df['new'] = \
df['1'] * np.cos(df['Ang'] * pi_div_180) + \
df['2'] * np.sin(df['Ang'] * pi_div_180) + \
df['3'] * np.sin(df['Ang'] * pi_div_180) * np.cos(df['Ang']*pi_div_180)
```

**Output**

```
            1         2         3  Ang       new
ID                                              
23   0.889053  0.500808  0.499545    0  0.889053
23   0.889053  0.500808  0.499545   10  1.047938
23   0.889053  0.500808  0.499545   20  1.167274
23   0.889053  0.500808  0.499545   30  1.236656
105  0.334210  0.240771  0.345252    0  0.334210
105  0.334210  0.240771  0.345252   10  0.429983
105  0.334210  0.240771  0.345252   20  0.507365
105  0.334210  0.240771  0.345252   30  0.559318
47   0.020669  0.154582  0.044396    0  0.020669
47   0.020669  0.154582  0.044396   10  0.054790
47   0.020669  0.154582  0.044396   20  0.086562
47   0.020669  0.154582  0.044396   30  0.114415
28   0.079131  0.987645  0.421184    0  0.079131
28   0.079131  0.987645  0.421184   10  0.321459
28   0.079131  0.987645  0.421184   20  0.547520
28   0.079131  0.987645  0.421184   30  0.744730
```

To drop the unnecessary columns, use `df.filter`:

```
df = df.filter(regex='\D')

     Ang       new
ID                
23     0  0.889053
23    10  1.047938
23    20  1.167274
23    30  1.236656
105    0  0.334210
105   10  0.429983
105   20  0.507365
105   30  0.559318
47     0  0.020669
47    10  0.054790
47    20  0.086562
47    30  0.114415
28     0  0.079131
28    10  0.321459
28    20  0.547520
28    30  0.744730
```

Comment: A dataset of 300 rows, speed shouldn't be an issue. I think it is good to see how it is done using a loop before going onto broadcasting which is a more advanced topic.

Comment: I disagree completely, people should learn the pandas API in the correct way from the start, even in the official documentation they warn for using loops, which sometimes can be 10000x slower. Pandas provides fast vectorized solutions for us. If you want use loops, then why use pandas instead of vanilla python?

Comment: I think this is good way, always the best is avoid loops, plus1

Comment: I agree avoiding loops and using vectorized operations is the way to go, but for a beginner asking to implement this simple solution, vectorization may be hard to conceptually understand.

Comment: @Erfan - How can I define the max angle and the increments as per user input? Suppose M is my max angle and the angular increments is A.

Comment: @Efran Should it be step=Ang? when creating the angles?

Comment: @Erfan -  I am getting an Value error ```cannot reindex from a duplicate axis```. My data set has repeating indexes but values are different. Kindly check my edited dataset

Comment: i have duplicate index row values in my data set.. But column values are different. Could you suggest some possible edit to the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
def equation(ang,a,b,c):
    return a*cos(ang*(pi/180)) + b*sin(ang*(pi/180)) + c* sin(ang*(pi/180))*cos(ang*(pi/180))

res = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ID","Ang","Result"])
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for ang in [0,10,20,30]:
        result = equation(ang,row[0],row[1],row[2])
        res = res.append({'ID':idx,'Ang':ang,'Result':result}, ignore_index=True)
```

This should be easy enough to follow, I created a function for you equation then I created an empty dataframe with columns as your expected outcome. Next I loop through the rows of the original dataframe, using the index of the original dataframe for the ID column in the new dataframe. Next I loop through the angles you mentioned above and store the respective ID, ang and "Result" by calling the equation function.